# K&R - getop() function

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have query regarding the getop function used in K&R at page-78.Below is the implementation.

```
/* getop: get next character or numeric operand */
 int getop(char s[])
{
int i, c;
while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
    ;
s[1] = '\0';

if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
    return c; /* not a number */

i = 0;
if (isdigit(c)) /* collect integer part */
    while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
        ;
if (c == '.') /* collect fraction part */
    while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
        ;
s[i] = '\0';

if (c != EOF)
    ungetch(c);

return NUMBER;
}
```

Suppose entered number is a digit then why we are starting from s[1] as below.
Why not from s[0] ?

```
i = 0;
if (isdigit(c)) /* collect integer part */
while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
```

Comment: `while ((s[0] = c = getch()`

Comment: The first while loop stores in `s[0]`; the second starts at 1 to avoid overwriting it.

Comment: had the same question... I think I was thrown off by `i = 0`, it made me think we are starting to parse there, but really the first character has already been parsed.... I even copied the the line incorrectly as `s[i++] = c = getch()` because my brain was already thinking that way...

Answer (score 2):

The `s[0]` already holds a *first* digit (or the decimal point). If this is not the case, then the function will have returned from here:

```
if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
    return c; /* not a number */
```

The `c` has been assigned to `s[0]` within the loop's condition:

```
while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
    ;
```